# Prevent duplicates record from being appended in Excel, Use latest value

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I have a very simple excel workbook that contains about 10 columns of inventory information. I have three mobile scanners that export data to the single workbook. I have it set to "append" so that the data is not overwritten but added to the workbook. How do I prevent a duplicate record from being added to the workbook based on the `AssetId` column and also if a duplicate is found, I'd like the latest to overwrite the record with the new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want this to occur automatically once the worksheet is changed and the newest data is added on at the end:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim assetIDRange, c3ll as Range
'all you need is an if statement here then.
If sdsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row <= 2 Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    lastRow = sdsheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End If

Set assetIDRange = thisworkbook.sheets("SheetName").Range("A2:A" & lastRow - 1)

newAssetID = thisworkbook.sheets("SheetName").cells(lastRow, 1)

For each c3ll in assetIDRange
    if c3ll.value = newAssetID then
        c3ll.entirerow.delete
        exit sub
    end if
next c3ll

End Sub
```

Be sure to change `"SheetName"` to the actual name of your Sheet.  And this has to be done in Worksheet and not a new module.

If there is data you wish to change in the old row than inside the if statement find the old row using `c3ll.row` and change the data way.

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error 1004 when added new data that contains duplicated to the worksheet. When hitting debug its telling me the problem is in this line: 'Set assetIDRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AssetsTracked").Range("A2:A" & lastRow - 1)

Comment: how many rows do you have? are there more than 911 characters in those cells or is that your column for assetID number (which I would assume has less than 911 characters)?

Comment: Is your first column empty? you would have to change A2:A to the letter of your column

Comment: I currently have 10 columns, the first one being assetID, i tried with no data first then with one record saved and both times I got the runtime error.

Comment: The only time I was able to duplicate the error is when I had no data in column A.  What does lastRow equal when you step through the code?

Comment: lastRow equals = 1 when I debug.

Comment: so you are in the wrong column, this is set up as if your assetIDs are in column A. You are going to need to change `Cells(rows.end, 1)` to `Cells(row.end, NUMBER OF YOUR COLUMN HERE)` Then change everywhere it looks for column A to the letter of the column your assetIDs are in.

Comment: thats the thing, my 'assetID' Column is in column A which is why I'm stumped. I Would really appreciate if you could maybe email me the worksheet you have working possibly? hkstc@yahoo.com

Comment: emailed you about 1 minute ago

Comment: Got it, it works when you have the spreadsheet pre-populated. I'm looking for a solution that does not require rows to contain data so that the initial scanner export doesn't fail. Thank you so much working with me though ! :)